# App Crashing on Android 9 while inserting media file

Tags: android, android-permissions, mediastore, android-contentresolver

Media Insertion Code:

```
fun saveVideoToExternalStorage(
    contentResolver: ContentResolver,
    displayName: String,
    file: File
): Uri {
    val videoCollection = if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.Q)
        MediaStore.Video.Media.getContentUri(MediaStore.VOLUME_EXTERNAL_PRIMARY)
    else MediaStore.Video.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI

    val contentValues = ContentValues().apply {
        put(MediaStore.Video.Media.TITLE, displayName)
        put(MediaStore.Video.Media.MIME_TYPE, "video/mp4")
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.Q) {
            put(MediaStore.Video.Media.DISPLAY_NAME, displayName)
            put(
                MediaStore.Video.Media.RELATIVE_PATH,
                "${Environment.DIRECTORY_MOVIES}/Coutloot"
            )
        } else {
            var videosDir =
                Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES).path
            videosDir += "/Coutloot"

            with(File(videosDir, displayName)) {
                put(MediaStore.Video.Media.DATA, path)
                parentFile?.let {
                    if (!it.exists()) {
                        it.mkdir()
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
    return try {
        val uri = contentResolver.insert(videoCollection, contentValues)?.also { uri ->
            contentResolver.openOutputStream(uri).use { outputStream ->
                outputStream?.write(file.readBytes())
            }
        } ?: throw IOException("Couldn't create MediaStore entry")
        uri
    } catch (e: IOException) {
        e.printStackTrace()
        Uri.EMPTY
    }
}
```

While saving app crashes on **contentResolver.insert**

Here's the crash log

```
2021-11-17 18:43:00.979 785-785/company.coutloot W/System.err: java.lang.SecurityException: Permission Denial: writing com.android.providers.media.MediaProvider uri content://media/external/images/media from pid=785, uid=10533 requires android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE, or grantUriPermission()
```

I tried adding running time permission too, but it did not work and this is only happening in Android 9.
Can anyone suggest me how to fix this?

Comment: Have you allowed storage permission for the app?

Answer (score 0):

Try this code it works for me

```
var fileOutputStream : OutputStream?

if(Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.Q){
    contentResolver.also { resolver ->
        val contentValues = ContentValues().apply {
            put(MediaStore.Video.Media.DISPLAY_NAME,displayName)
            put(MediaStore.Video.Media.MIME_TYPE,"video/mp4")
            put(MediaStore.Video.Media.RELATIVE_PATH,"${Environment.DIRECTORY_MOVIES}/Coutloot")
        }

        val videoUri = resolver.insert(
            MediaStore.Video.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI,contentValues
        )
        fileOutputStream = videoUri?.let {
            resolver.openOutputStream(it)
        }
    }
}else{
    val absolutePath =
        Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS).absolutePath

    val path = absolutePath.substring(0, absolutePath.length - 5) + "/Coutloot/"
    val filePath = File(path)
    if (!filePath.exists())
        filePath.mkdir()

    fileOutputStream = FileOutputStream(
        File(filePath, displayName)
    )
}

fileOutputStream?.write(file.readBytes())
```

Comment: `if (!filePath.exists())
      if(!  filePath.mkdir()) return`